# Have float64 or float32 attribute in numba jitclass

Tags: python, numpy, numba

How to have a numba jitclass with an argument which can be either a float64 or a float32 ? With functions, the following code works:

```py
import numba
import numpy as np
from numba import njit
from numba.experimental import jitclass


@njit()
def f(a):
    print(a.dtype)
    return a[0]


a = np.zeros(3)
f(a)
f(a.astype(np.float32))
```

while trying to use both float32 and float64 with class attributes fails:

```py
@jitclass([('arr', numba.types.float64[:])])
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def f(self, a):
        self.arr = a


myclass = MyClass()
myclass.f(np.zeros(3))
# following line fails:
myclass.f(np.zeros(3, dtype=np.float32))
```

Is there a workaround ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `MyClass()`, Numba need to instantiate a class and because Numba only work with well-defined strongly types (this is what makes it fast and so useful), the field of the class need to be typed before the instantiation of an object. Thus, you cannot define the type of `MyClass` fields when the method `f` is called because this call is made by the CPython interpreter which is dynamic. Note that a class usually have more than one method (otherwise such a class would not be very useful) and this is why partial compilation is not really possible either.

One simple solution to address this problem is simply to use two types:

```py
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def f(self, a):
        self.arr = a

MyClass_float32 = jitclass([('arr', numba.types.float32[:])])(MyClass)
MyClass_float64 = jitclass([('arr', numba.types.float64[:])])(MyClass)

myclass = MyClass_float32() # Instantiate the class lazily and an object
# `self.arr` is already instantiated here and it has `float32[:]` type.
myclass.f(np.zeros(3, dtype=np.float32))

myclass = MyClass_float64()
myclass.f(np.zeros(3, dtype=np.float64))
```

Comment: Thank you Jérôme. My confusion comes from the fact that for a function, you can call it providing both float32 and float64. What makes it work in the case of a function ? Because there is still some code compiled at the first call, right ?

Comment: The type of `self.arr` is set when `MyClass_float32()` is called because `MyClass_float32` is actually a JITed function that return a well-defined type containing `self.arr`. The type of a field in a compiled class cannot change at runtime. As for functions, you can have multiple *overloads* with different signatures (ie. parameter types).

Answer (score 0):

Numba supports templated kernels but by custom selection of types like this:

```
import numpy as np

from numba import generated_jit, types

@generated_jit(nopython=True)
def is_missing(x):
    """
    Return True if the value is missing, False otherwise.
    """
    if isinstance(x, types.Float):
        return lambda x: np.isnan(x)
    elif isinstance(x, (types.NPDatetime, types.NPTimedelta)):
        # The corresponding Not-a-Time value
        missing = x('NaT')
        return lambda x: x == missing
    else:
        return lambda x: Fals
```

The trick is to use 'generated_jit' annotation.

Comment: How do you use this with classes ?